# Prevent NNPACK warnings using torch with python in DigitalOcean

Tags: python, pytorch, digital-ocean

I've developed a python script that recognizes QR codes in documents and images. I'm using [qrdet](https://github.com/Eric-Canas/qrdet) library that depends on torch. Everything is ok but when I run the script in DigitalOcean linux server I get this warning:

```
[W NNPACK.cpp:64] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
```

It's just a warning because after that the process continues and shows me the QR data. I have to remove that warning because I'm using python output from other process that expects a valid JSON.

I've tried these workarounds with no results:

1. Setting variable USE_NNPACK=0 before running the script `export USE_NNPACK=0`
2. Setting variable USE_NNPACK=0 before installing torch
3. Setting variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" before running the script
4. Reinstalled torch with `pip3 install torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`
5. Configuring torch inside the script:

```py
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
x = x.to('cpu')
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False
torch.cuda.is_available = lambda : False
```

6. Removing warnings with warning package

### Versions

```
PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cpu
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: None
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.27.4
Libc version: glibc-2.27

Python version: 3.8.0 (default, Dec  9 2021, 17:53:27)  [GCC 8.4.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-4.15.0-213-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: No CUDA
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: No CUDA
Nvidia driver version: No CUDA
cuDNN version: No CUDA
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               63
Model name:          DO-Regular
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             2199.996
BogoMIPS:            4399.99
Virtualization:      VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt arat md_clear

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.24.4
[pip3] torch==2.0.1+cpu
[pip3] torchvision==0.15.2+cpu
[conda] Could not collect
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Installing cmake on my Arch Linux helped out!

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cmake
```